# Unix script - Mismatch in CLI output and script output

Tags: unix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFctr.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viEEf.png)

```
root@server1:~# ps ax|grep -v grep|grep hds|awk '{ print $1 }'|wc -l
6
```

The same command inside a shell script shows output for `wc -l` as `8`

i get a mismatch when i check the process count in CLI and script.
Why is it showing 8 instead of 6?

Comment: What is the name of your shell script? I suggest to show the code of your script. Please [edit] your question and add this information, don't answer in comments. To debug this, show the output after `grep hds` or save it in a file, e.g. with `ps ax | grep -v grep | grep hds | tee grep_output.log | awk '{ print $1 }' | wc -l` Then you can see what processes match your pattern. If this doesn't help, show the resulting file when you run this from your shell script.

Comment: i added the code and the output click the link to open it

Comment: Copy&paste the code and output **as text** instead of showing screenshots, Show the resulting file `grep_output.log`